# ScrollMagic SVG Drawing Text

Tags: scrollmagic

I can not figure out why my svg is not drawing.
I get no "real" errors on my console (The "WARNING: tween was overwritten by another" is not relevant here)

You can see the full demo here:
http://mc-communicate.com/test/svg.html

Here are the relevant codes:

SVG HTML:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="1095" height="299" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

          <path id="c" d="m102,91.8c3,-0.5 5.6,-2.5 8.7,-2.5c3.10001,0.6 3.5,4.2 4.3,6.8c-2.4,-0.7 -4.7,-1.6 -7,-2.4c-10.4,8.5 -21.4,17.3 -27.9,29.4c-4.7,8.00001 -4.1,18.9 1.7,26.00001c4.6,5.7 12.1,8 19.2,8.09999c6.8,0 13.6,-0.89999 20.2,-2.09999c8.10001,-1.5 15.8,-4.8 23.90001,-6.10001c-12.40001,9.10001 -27.7,14.10001 -43.10001,15.10001c-8.5,0.5 -17.6,-0.3 -24.8,-5.40001c-8.5,-5.59999 -12.5,-16.7 -10.89999,-26.7c1.8,-10.9 6.8,-21.3 14.39999,-29.3c2.4,-2.8 5.7,-4.5 8.9,-6.2c2.8,-1.3 4.2,-4.4 6.7,-6.1c2,0.3 3.8,1.1 5.7,1.4z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="o" d="m179.10001,114c17.2,-2 35.29999,-1.7 51.29999,5.6c8.8,4 15.5,12.7 16.20001,22.50001c0.2,3.2 0.79999,7.2 -1.90001,9.59999c-9.2,9.90001 -22.59999,14.60001 -35.5,17.40001c-15.39999,2.79999 -32.5,1.39999 -45.59999,-7.70001c-2.90001,-2.39999 -7,-5 -6.70001,-9.29999c0,-8.3 2.3,-17 8,-23.20001c4.70001,-5.39999 11,-8.89999 17.3,-12.2c-1,-0.89999 -2,-1.8 -3.09999,-2.7m16.29999,7.7c-5.5,0.60001 -10.29999,3.5 -15.39999,5.2c-3.8,1.2 -7.39999,2.99999 -9.89999,6.2c-3.20001,3.2 -3.8,7.59999 -4.10001,11.89999c0,2.89999 -2.60001,6.39999 0.10001,8.8c4.79999,5.09999 11.79999,8.5 18.89999,8.5c8.7,0.2 17.39999,0.09999 26.10001,-1.10001c4.79999,-0.7 9.7,-0.2 14.5,-0.8c7.29999,-1.79999 13.09999,-8.79999 13.29999,-16.39999c0.5,-6.7 -3.09999,-13.5 -8.89999,-17c-4.8,-3 -10.39999,-3.8 -15.8,-5.2c-6.2,-1.60001 -12.59999,-0.8 -18.8,-0.10001z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="m" d="m269.20001,156.10001c10.89999,-13.40001 13.39999,-32.2 26.79999,-43.7c1.79999,1.2 4.70001,1.9 4.60001,4.6c0.89999,8.4 1.60001,16.89999 3.79999,25.10001c6.60001,-5 8.39999,-13.40001 12.5,-20.2c2.30002,-3.9 6.39999,-6.1 10.70001,-7c0.79999,9.7 2.60001,19.9 9,27.49999c4,4.8 11.10001,7.90001 17.10001,5.3c3.79999,-1.59999 7.5,-3.59999 11.69998,-4c-1,6.2 -7.69998,8 -12.60001,10.10001c-5.89999,2.7 -12.59998,0.5 -17.69998,-2.90001c-6.70001,-4.79999 -10.70001,-12.39999 -13.80002,-19.89999c-5.39999,5.3 -6.5,13.3 -11.09998,19.10001c-2.20001,2.89999 -5.80002,4 -9.20001,4.5c-4.70001,-8.90001 -5.39999,-19.20001 -7.39999,-28.90001c-9.30002,12.5 -13.30002,27.8 -18.89999,42.10001c-1.5,2.89999 -5,3.8 -7.60001,5.39999c-4.89999,-13.3 -9.89999,-26.89999 -11,-41.09999c-0.10001,-5.10001 -0.20001,-11.40001 4.29999,-14.7c1.89999,-0.6 3.70001,1.1 4.5,2.7c1.39999,3.1 1.20001,6.6 1.30002,9.9c0,8.8 0.29999,17.7 3,26.10001z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="i" d="m380.10001,113c1.10001,-1.8 3.5,-0.9 4.79999,0.2c0.20001,5.3 -0.69998,10.5 -0.39999,15.8c0.5,13.39999 7,25.5 11.60001,37.8c-1.60001,0.5 -3.30002,1 -4.89999,1.5c-6.90002,-10.8 -11.80002,-22.90001 -14.10001,-35.5c-0.80002,-6.60001 -1.89999,-14.4 3,-19.8z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="idot" d="m380.5,78.8c2.20001,-0.3 4.70001,-1.60001 6.60001,0.1c3.79999,3 6.19998,7.3 8.89999,11.3c-4.29999,1.8 -8.10001,-1.6 -11.5,-3.7c-2.79999,-1.6 -3.29999,-4.9 -4,-7.7z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="n" d="m444.39999,125.3c2,0 4,0.1 6,0.1c3.39999,10.99999 6,22.2 10.5,32.8c3.70001,9.3 10.80002,17.10001 19.10001,22.8c4.70001,3.3 10.70001,3.5 16.10001,2.2c5.5,-1.09999 10.29999,-4.09999 15.39999,-6.39999c-1.10001,3.39999 -3.79999,6 -6.89999,7.7c-4,2.10001 -7.80002,5.5 -12.60001,4.8c-10.29999,-0.8 -21.29999,-3.90001 -28.29999,-12c-10.70001,-11.10001 -14.10001,-26.60001 -18.70001,-40.8c-10.5,9 -12.29999,23.89999 -22.20001,33.3c-2.19998,2.2 -4.79999,3.7 -7.5,5.09999c-1.69998,-2 -3.59998,-3.89999 -4.89999,-6.2c-0.10001,-5.8 0.70001,-11.59999 0.10001,-17.5c-0.60001,-8.3 -0.89999,-17.59999 4.79999,-24.39999c2.10001,0.89999 4.70001,1.59999 5.90002,3.8c0,4.5 -1.60001,9 -1.70001,13.59999c0,4.60001 -0.29999,9.2 -0.60001,13.90001c9.60001,-10.10001 16.80002,-22 25.5,-32.8z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="g" d="m524.5,125.5c8.20001,-5.1 20.90002,-3.9 26.09998,4.89999c3.20001,4.8 1.70001,10.8 0.60004,16c2.59998,-1.29999 5,-3.2 7.79999,-4.09999c1.59998,-0.10001 4,0.39999 4.20001,2.39999c1.70001,9.90001 -0.29999,20.3 3.29999,29.90001c1.40002,3.29999 -1,6.89999 0.70001,10.09999c7.09998,19.10001 17.09998,36.90001 28.09998,54c3.79999,5.3 2.40002,12.3 2.5,18.40001c0.29999,6.29999 -6,9.89999 -11.09998,11.60001c-15.79999,4.79999 -33,2.59998 -48.29999,-3.10001c-6.40002,-2.60001 -13.40002,-5.89999 -16.60004,-12.3c-3.79999,-8.2 -3,-17.8 -1.59998,-26.5c1.5,9.59999 2.70001,20.09999 9.09998,27.89999c2.10004,2.8 5.70001,3.3 8.90002,4.2c7.89996,1.89999 15.79999,3.80002 23.79999,5.20001c4.40002,0.89999 8.70001,-1.30002 12.90002,-2.20001c4.79999,-1.29999 10.39996,-2.19998 13.69995,-6.39999c1.10004,-1.2 0.5,-2.89999 0.30005,-4.3c-5.5,-23.7 -23.60004,-41.89999 -29.60004,-65.5c-1.79999,-9.8 -1.09998,-20.2 -5.59998,-29.5c-2.5,0.60001 -5.10004,1 -7.5,2c-2.29999,0.90001 -3.5,4 -6.20001,4c-9.40002,0.40001 -17.59998,5.2 -26.59998,7.2c-5.40002,1.20001 -11.50003,2.60001 -16.70001,-0.2c-4.20001,-2.2 -6.20001,-7.5 -4.70001,-12c2.39999,-8 8.60001,-14.2 14.79999,-19.5c5.5,-4.59999 11.70001,-8.3 17.70001,-12.2m9.29999,5.3c-7.29999,2.2 -13.59998,6.7 -19.39996,11.5c-5.80002,4.89999 -11.30002,10.5 -14.40002,17.59999c6.20001,2.60001 13.20001,3.40001 19.79999,1.8c10,-2.39999 19.70001,-6.39999 28.90002,-11.09999c1.20001,-3.70001 0.59998,-7.8 0.79999,-11.70001c0.09998,-3.29999 -2.59998,-5.59999 -5.09998,-7.39999c-3.10004,-2.10001 -7.20001,-1.7 -10.60004,-0.7z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="s" d="m702,92c6.5,-2.9 14.20001,-3.4 20.70001,-0.2c-1.10004,6.3 -5.70001,11.1 -11.5,13.5c-1.10004,-1.2 -2.10004,-2.5 -3.40002,-3.60001c-10.59998,0.5 -17.89996,9.3 -25.79999,15.3c10.79999,0.9 21.70001,1 32.5,2.4c11.20001,1.1 22.79999,3.2 32.40002,9.7c3.09998,1.7 2.59998,5.79999 2.59998,8.89999c-0.40002,9.89999 -7.59998,17.89999 -15.70001,22.8c-6.20001,4 -13.70001,5 -19.79999,9.2c-3.40002,2.10001 -7.20001,5.2 -11.5,3.5c-7,-2.2 -9.20001,-10.7 -7.40002,-17.2c3.30005,2.2 2,8.7 6.90002,8.59999c7.20001,0.8 13.20001,-3.7 19.29999,-6.7c4.40002,-2.5 9.29999,-4.3 12.90002,-8c2.70001,-4 4.09998,-8.8 7.59998,-12.3c-6.09998,-9.2 -17.89996,-11.3 -28.09998,-12.39999c-11.29999,-1.4 -22.5,0.5 -33.70001,1.7c-4.29999,0 -9.59998,0.7 -13.09998,-2.39999c0.19995,-3.5 1.29999,-7.3 4,-9.9c1.5,-0.4 3.19995,-0.4 4.89996,-0.5c7.29999,-8.9 15.29999,-17.9 26.20001,-22.4z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>



          <path id="otwo" d="m781.09998,114c17.20001,-2 35.30005,-1.7 51.30005,5.6c8.79999,4 15.5,12.7 16.19995,22.50001c0.20001,3.2 0.80005,7.2 -1.79999,9.59999c-9.09998,9.7 -22.20001,14.40001 -34.79999,17.2c-15.59998,3.10001 -33.09998,1.8 -46.40002,-7.5c-2.89996,-2.39999 -7,-5 -6.69995,-9.29999c0,-8.3 2.29999,-17 8,-23.20001c4.69995,-5.39999 11,-8.99999 17.29999,-12.2c-1,-0.89999 -2,-1.8 -3.10004,-2.7m-8.29999,20.8c-2.59998,1.89999 -1.89996,5.2 -2.39996,8c-0.40002,3.2 -2.5,5.7 -4.20001,8.3c4.09998,6.79999 12.09998,10 19.70001,10.79999c11.39996,1.10001 23,0.20001 34.19995,-1.7c4.60004,-0.7 8.20001,-3.8 12.10004,-6c3.5,-2.09999 7,-5.09999 8,-9.3c1.09998,-4.89999 -0.90002,-10.2 -4,-14c-4,-4.99999 -10.20001,-7.2 -16.29999,-7.99999c-0.5,4.5 0.09998,9.49999 -2.5,13.49999c-0.90002,0.90001 -3.40002,2.3 -3.70001,0.3c0,-1.7 0.5,-3.39999 0.5,-5.09999c-3.29999,-7.40001 -12.20001,-11.50001 -20,-9.3c-8,2.3 -15.29999,6.8 -21.40002,12.5z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
          <path id="othree" d="m899.40002,113.6c5.59998,-1.3 11.39996,0.1 17,1c9.09998,1.9 18.79999,4.7 25.29999,11.8c5.5,5.9 8,14.4 6.79999,22.4c-0.29999,1.59999 -1.70001,2.8 -2.70001,4c-7.09998,7 -16.5,11.2 -25.89996,14.09999c-13.40002,4.20001 -28.10004,4.90001 -41.5,0.70001c-7.30005,-2.40001 -14.90002,-6.10001 -19.20001,-12.8c-0.79999,-5.5 0.29999,-11.2 2.09998,-16.5c3.20001,-9 11.10004,-15.3 19.29999,-19.7c5.80005,-3.3 12.60004,-3.1 18.80005,-5m-6,8.9c-10.10004,2.7 -17.5,10.39999 -26.30005,15.7c-3.29999,3.3 -2.89996,8.90001 -1.19995,12.90001c3.39996,5.59999 9.79999,8.59999 15.89996,10.09999c5.90002,1.40001 11,5.5 17.20001,5.3c10.40002,-1.10001 20.59998,-4.5 29.40002,-10.10001c4,-2.39999 8.69995,-4.7 10.89996,-9.09999c2.5,-4.90001 0.70001,-10.90001 -2.29999,-15.3c-3.40002,-5 -9.29999,-7.7 -15.09998,-8.9c-5.20001,-1.4 -10.60004,-0.5 -15.90002,-0.8c-4.20001,-0.2 -8.5,-1 -12.59998,0.2z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>


          <path id="ntwo" d="m992.40002,125.3c2,0 4,0.1 6,0.1c2.09998,6.99999 4.09998,13.99999 6.19995,20.99999c3,9.40001 6.5,19.10001 13.70001,26.3c5.29999,5.3 11.60004,11.5 19.70001,11.2c7.80005,0.10001 14.69995,-3.79999 21.5,-7.09999c-1.09998,3.39999 -3.80005,6 -6.90002,7.7c-4,2.10001 -7.79993,5.5 -12.59998,4.8c-10.30005,-0.90001 -21.29999,-3.90001 -28.29999,-12c-10.70001,-11.10001 -14.10004,-26.60001 -18.70001,-40.8c-10.70001,9.10001 -12.40002,24.5 -22.70001,33.8c-2.09998,1.89999 -4.59998,3.3 -7,4.59999c-1.70001,-2 -3.59998,-3.89999 -4.89996,-6.2c-0.10004,-5.5 0.59998,-11.09999 0.19995,-16.59999c-0.59998,-8.60001 -1.19995,-18.20001 4.70001,-25.3c2.10004,0.89999 4.70001,1.59999 5.90002,3.8c0,4.5 -1.60004,9 -1.60004,13.59999c-0.09998,4.60001 -0.39996,9.2 -0.69995,13.90001c9.59998,-10.10001 16.79999,-22 25.5,-32.8z" stroke-width="0.09375" stroke="#7644b6" fill="#7644b6">
          </path>
        </svg>
```

JS:

```
<script>
          function pathPrepare ($el) {
            var lineLength = $el[0].getTotalLength();
            $el.css("stroke-dasharray", lineLength);
            $el.css("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength);
          }

          var $c = $("path#c");
          var $o = $("path#o");
          var $m = $("path#m");
          var $i = $("path#i");
          var $idot = $("path#idot");
          var $n = $("path#n");
          var $g = $("path#g");
          var $s = $("path#s");
          var $otwo = $("path#otwo");
          var $othree = $("path#othree");
          var $ntwo = $("path#ntwo");

          // prepare SVG
          pathPrepare($c);
          pathPrepare($o);
          pathPrepare($m);
          pathPrepare($i);
          pathPrepare($idot);
          pathPrepare($n);
          pathPrepare($g);
          pathPrepare($s);
          pathPrepare($otwo);
          pathPrepare($othree);
          pathPrepare($ntwo);

          // init controller
          var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

          // build tween
          var tween = new TimelineMax()
              .add(TweenMax.to($c, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($o, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($m, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($i, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($idot, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($n, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($g, 0.9, {   
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($s, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($otwo, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($othree, 0.9, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              )) // draw word for 0.9
              .add(TweenMax.to($ntwo, 0.1, {
                strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              ))  // draw dot for 0.1
              .add(TweenMax.to("path", 20, {
                stroke: "#33629c", ease:Linear.easeNone}
                              ), 0);
          // change color during the whole thing

          // build scene
          var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: "#trigger1", duration: 200, tweenChanges: true}
                                           )
              .setTween(tween)
              .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
              .addTo(controller);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that you actually don't use paths, but shapes with fills.
You can only animate strokes this way, not fillings.
The stroke in this case is the (invisible) outline of each letter.

That is why it's not working.

regards,
J

Comment: Oh great, thank you ;) The best answers are coming from the authors themselves ;)